# NSubstitue mock IEnumerable Where() method

Tags: linq, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I have the following code:

`45  var listMock = Substitute.For<List<EntityTestObject>>();
 46  listMock.Where(Arg.Any<Func<EntityTestObject, bool>>()).Returns(Something);`

But I'm getting the following error:

`System.ArgumentNullException` : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: predicate
   at `System.Linq.Enumerable.Where[TSource](IEnumerable'1 source, Func'2 predicate)`
   at line 46.

However, methods that does not take `func<>` arguments, such as Any(), do not fail.

My questions are:

- How to avoid this mistake if it possible?
- If not, how to mock Enumerable Extension methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSubstitute can not mock extension methods like `Enumerable.Where<T>`. For the case of a `List` I would advise not mocking it at all. Use a real list and add the items you need for your test, so that the real `Where(..)` extension method will filter the items and provide the items required.